# Is there a template system like Twig that uses PHP syntax?

Tags: php, twig

I would like to use a template system like Twig (specifically the block functionality) but in plain PHP.

For example, I found http://phpsavant.com/docs/ but it seems that doesn't support blocks or anything similar.

**Edit**
I found something that appears to have block syntax with regular PHP code: http://phpti.com/

Comment: What do you mean by block functionality? That foreach loop in Savant's sample code looks good enough for me. And really, if you want plain PHP, just use [plain PHP](http://phptemplatinglanguage.com).

Comment: a block in this is something you define in a template, but that can be render in a totally different template.

For example: in the general layout you define a block for the title of the page, then, in each template you populate the content of that block. So you set content_for "title" => "This is the title", but it is rendered in the layout

Answer (score 3):

The templating language you are looking for is called PHP!

Comment: Not a very constructive response.

Answer (score 1):

There is one included in the Laravel framework called [*Blade*](http://four.laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating).

You can mix plain old PHP with the Blade templating syntax, where `{{...}}` also translates to `<?=...?>` or `<?php echo ... ?>`

Also has blocks you know in Twig, but they are called `sections`.

```
@section('heading')
    {{ strtoupper("I'm not shouting") }}
@show

<?= strtolower('Shhh!'); ?>
```

This is under the `Illuminate\View` namespace - [See on GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/master/src/Illuminate/View), and can be downloaded with Composer as it is also registered on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/view) - just at the following to your project's composer.json.

```
{
    "require": {
        "illuminate/view": "4.*"
    }
}
```

I'm not certain at this point about how you'd attempt to render a template from a custom project. If I find out, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony (which uses Twig by default) also has a php-based template system that works very much like Twig. It has template inheritance and uses 'slots', which are equivalent to Twig's blocks. It's a stand-alone library that can be used outside of the full Symfony framework.

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/templating/PHP.html

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a templating language(yes it is) , blocks can be implemented with buffers :

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
  this the content of the block for <?= date("Y-m-d") ?>
<?php
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

then in the main layout echo the content of the blocks :

```
echo $head;
echo $content ;
// ....
```

in fact that is what most template engines are using.

using template libs have huge advantages though ( caching , escaping by default ,etc ... )

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand use off `Blade` for views is optional in `Laravel`. You can use file name like `view.php` instead of `view.blade.php` and use plain old PHP syntax there. Only catch is you cannot have both `view.php` and `view.blade.php` as they both respond to

```
return View::make('view);
```